# Displaying arc within a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, trigonometry

There is a problem:
Have a rectangle, the coordinates of the lower left corner - (0, 0), upper right (width of the rectangle, the height of the rectangle). Inside this rectangle is the point having certain coordinates. I need to draw around this point a segment of a circle with a certain (const) arc length. Calculate the internal radius and the angle of the segment of a circle.
illustration:

[image]

Like this. As can be seen from the figure, if the segment to be placed in the side of the screen (eg bottom left), it is necessary to find such a range that it satisfies our long arc.
Prompt, in what side to search?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: that's just some basic trigonometry. where's the problem? what have you got so far?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your comment. I have to calculate distance in X and Y axis. Then if the point is too near to both borders, i calculate radius and arc angle for every axis. The problem is that radius depends on arc angle and arc angle depends on radius. And thats why it's impossible to merge radius and arc angle from every axis. Thats why i'm asking for some another solution.

Comment: That's rather a general problem with your question than anything algorithm-related. Try to define a more specific behavior for your algorithm. The current version has a lot of holes that allow random behavior. E.g: this definition would allow to simply generate arcs with minimum angle and maximum radius or vice versa.